# C# windows service - Best way to call method every second (w/o Windows.Forms.Timer)

Tags: c#, timer

I would like to call a method every second.
Normally the method will finish after a few milliseconds. But sometimes it can be that it takes 2 to 3 seconds. What would be the best way to handle this without using Windows.Forms.Timer(single threaded).
My solution right now is to use System.Timers.Timer and set the _timer.AutoReset = false and after my "timer elapsed method" has finished I restart the timer with _timer.Start()

Is there a better way to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: This would depend on what your method does, which you haven't told us.

Comment: *almost* any time you are using a timer in a service like this, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: My method is reading/writing to an external device. This takes normally only some milliseconds, but sometimes it takes longer (dependig on the external device system load).

toCMasMas: OK, but what would be better?

Comment: Your method is ok if you actually need the timer.  An example of what I am referring to is If you are trying to do something every time a file changes (for instance), you can get an event fired to do the work rather than ***pulling*** to see if work needs to be done.  If you are doing things ***no matter what*** every second, then the timer is probably the way to go.

Comment: The second one is my goal. I need to read the data from the external device to see if they changed or not. And this I need to to every second(can be 1s or 1.1s or 1.2 - this doesnt matter). So my way I expained above (_timer.AutoReset = false and after my method call _timer.Start()) is correct?

Comment: If your external device is actually a storage device, you should use a [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

A timer executes at a given interval. That is the definition of a timer as used in the .net framework. If you want different behavior, perhaps a timer is not what you are looking for. If I understand your question correctly you want to space out the method calls with 1 second between instead.

One way to accomplish this is by using an async task.

```
//in your start method
Task.Run(() => YourRepeatingTask(CancellationToken.None));

private async Task YourRepeatingTask(CancellationToken token)
{
  while (true) //check for conditions here
  {
    //Do stuff here

    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), token);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is probably how I would approach this problem, however, instead of looping indefinitely (`while(true)`), I would check the cancellation token at the start of every loop and exit if cancellation is requested. This would allow the service to shut down gracefully.

Comment: @PatrickTucci The while check gets executed directly after the delay. I do not think the additional token check would change anything. Though I guess in some cases it might make the intent more clear.

Comment: I understand where the  `while()` is executed. My point is that `while(true)` will execute forever, no matter what. Checking the cancellation token instead of using `while(true)` will allow calling functions to gracefully end the execution of `YourRepeatingTask()` instead of forcibly killing or ending it.